# Element width varies in chrome and in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the below code,

```html
<div class="Wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 20%; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="customText" style="width: auto; font-size: 33px; float: left; min-width: 10%;">Test</div>
    <div class="valueContainer" style="height: 100%; max-width: 90%;">
        <div class="value" id="containercardElementCard1_ActValue" style="width: auto; color: rgb(104, 98, 98); line-height: 55px; font-size: 33px; max-width: 100%;" data-tooltip="Value: ">7,632,789,549</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the wrapper width is `247px`.

In chrome, `customText` div takes `38.5px` width and `valueContainer` takes `208.4px`
whereas in IE, `customText` takes `60.3px` and `valueContainer` takes `186.6px`

I suspect that the `max-width` property is not working in IE.

Comment: unless you're using IE6, max-width is supported by IE, [see](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-width)

Comment: 90% of 247 is 222 pixels, so if IE's width is 186 pixels, that's no indication that `max-width:90%` doesn't work.

Comment: Are the browsers using the same font? Also, you use `justify-content`, does that mean the wrapper is a flex container? In that case, you don't need float.

Comment: `max-width` is in percentage. So it depends `90%` and `100%` of what ? And please do not use `floats`

Comment: @MrLister Yes.,the wrapper is a flex container and i removed the float but it remains the same

Comment: I made a test with above posted code. I did not get any difference in the output of both browsers. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/L6x10vrr/131.png Even I try to set window width to 247 px. Than also both browser gave same result. https://i.postimg.cc/VLkSMnd4/132.png Can you please try to post a screenshot of the issue with your testing result. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The cause of this bug is: IE simply refuses to size an element smaller than the set font size.

Best way to deal with this bug is to apply `overflow: hidden` to the element so it collapses to the intended height.